# from Octave's fminunc to Julia's optimize with gradient function with parameters

Tags: matlab, optimization, julia, octave, gradient

I am passing my code from octave to julia, in this case a logistic regression. The gradient function takes in addition to the initial theta, X with my features and Y with the sought values.

in Octave works

`function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)`
`options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);`
`[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);`

on Julia first try

```
optimize(t->CostFunction(t, X1, y), initial_theta, BFGS())
```

MethodError: no method matching -(::Tuple{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}, ::Tuple{Float64,Array{Float64,2}})

so I separated the function in two: Cost and Gradient

```
function CostFunction2(theta, X, y)
J = 0;
#m = length(y);
m = size(y,1);
grad = zeros(size(theta));
J = 1/m * sum( (-y .* log.(sigmoid(X*theta))) - ((1.0 .- y) .* log.(1.0 .- sigmoid(X*theta))) );
return J;
end


function Gradient2(X, y, theta)
grad = zeros(size(theta));
grad = (1/m) .* (sum((sigmoid(X*theta).-y) .* X, dims=1))';
return grad;
end
```

I put only the cost function and it worked, but I don't have the last values of theta. I don't know how to get it

```
optimize(t->CostFunction2(t, X1, y), initial_theta, BFGS())
```

I tried this but it didn't work, and I can't find any reference that says how or brings an example

```
optimize(t->CostFunction2(t, X1, y), Gradient2(X, y, t), initial_theta, BFGS())
```

UndefVarError: t not defined

How can I obtain the obtained theta values? and How can I include my own gradient function with various parameters?

I hope you can help me, thank you very much

Comment: can you please post your whole code in once piece. It seems that there is some simple problem with it (most likely that you are mixing scalars and vectors in an incorrect way). In particular note that in the call to `optimize` the `initial_theta` variable should be a vector not a scalar.

Comment: `data = load('data.txt');`
`X = data(:, [1, 2]); y = data(:, 3);`
`[m, n] = size(X);`
`X = [ones(m, 1) X];`
`initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);`

`function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)`
`J = 0;`
`m = size(y,1);`
`grad = zeros(size(theta));`
`J = -sum( (y .* log(sigmoid(X*theta))) + ((1-y) .* log(1 - sigmoid(X*theta))) ) / m;`
`grad = (1/m) * (sum((sigmoid(X*theta)-y) .* X))';`
`end`

`options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);`
`[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);`
`fprintf('Cost:%f theta:%f \n',cost,theta);`

Comment: `
using DelimitedFiles;
Data = readdlm("ex2data1.txt", ',', Float64);
X = Data[:,1:2];
y = Data[:,3];
m = length(y);
``
m,n = size(X);
X = [ones(m,1) X];
initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);
``
function CostFunction2(theta, X, y)
    J = 0;
    #m = length(y);
    m = size(y,1);
    grad = zeros(size(theta));
    J = 1/m * sum( (-y .* log.(sigmoid(X*theta))) - ((1.0 .- y) .* log.(1.0 .- sigmoid(X*theta))) );
    return J;
end
function Gradient2(X, y, theta)
    grad = zeros(size(theta));
    grad = (1/m) .* (sum((sigmoid(X*theta).-y) .* X, dims=1))';
    return grad;
end
`

Comment: `
using Optim;
optimize(t->CostFunction2(t, X1, y), Gradient2(X, y, t), initial_theta, BFGS());
`

Comment: Sorry for the code format. The first part is how I did it in Octave, the other two is how I did it in Julia. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned typos in your code, added missing definitions, and removed unnecessary operations.

After these changes the following works:

```
using DelimitedFiles

Data = readdlm("ex2data1.txt", ',', Float64)
X = Data[:,1:2]
y = Data[:,3]
m, n = size(X)
X = [ones(m) X]
initial_theta = zeros(n + 1)

sigmoid(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

function CostFunction2(theta, X, y)
    Xt = X*theta # do this step outside as it is repeated twice otherwise
    return sum(-y .* log.(sigmoid.(Xt)) .- (1.0 .- y) .* log.(1.0 .- sigmoid.(Xt)))
end

using Optim
optimize(t->CostFunction2(t, X, Y), initial_theta, BFGS())
```

Comment: Thanks for this cleaner and clearer code, helps me to continue learning to better code my linear algebra, and Julia's. Although as I said at the beginning, without a gradient function, it did work for me, and it returns the value of the cost function very well, only that in this part I do not know how to take the values of Theta, solved and I can use it, to get this cost.

Comment: The other part I think is a question of syntax, of how to put my own gradient function, and that it can receive additional parameters. It's not just that I want to pass my Octave code as is, this is just an example to be able to pass other more complicated algorithms that I am interested in testing. Thank you very much for your interest and help.

Comment: Here https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/latest/#user/gradientsandhessians/#example you can find the explanation how to pass a gradient (I am not updating my answer with it as I have not calculated the gradient formula, but the general idea is that you pass a vector that is to hold a gradient as a parameter to the function and it should be updated in place). In order to allow the gradient function to depend on some external parameters use a closure (define a function within a function).

Comment: Thank you very much, this example is more complete than the ones I had seen. Now I can get the Theta, the most important thing is that it is already useful to me, I was missing the 'Optim.minimizer'. Now I have theta
`Optim.minimizer(optimize(t->CostFunction2(t, X1, y), initial_theta, BFGS()))` Out[21]: 3×1 Array{Float64,2}:
 -25.16133454707563   
   0.20623172126187428
   0.20147160832867456

Now I will continue trying how to enter the gradient function with more parameters, which is still not clear to me. If I find a way to do it I will upload the example, someone else can use it.